# Arrays not working Cloud Code? - parse.com

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Very simply put, I cannot use the push method on Arrays in parse.com cloud code:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("some string");
```

When I look to see what the value of arr is:

```
console.log(arr); // []
```

I get an empty array. My mind is boggled. What am I missing?

Comment: what is the context of the two pieces of code? do you do the console.log as the next line after the push?

Comment: Yes, I console.log() right after to check that it was pushed:

`var arr = [];
arr.push("some string");
console.log(arr); // []`

Answer (score 0):

Mine is set up like this:

```
var arrObjects = {};
    arrObjects["Title"] = "title goes here or a get param";

receipts.push(arrObjects);

response.success(receipts);  
console.log(receipts);
```

`receipts` now in this filled.